# What is the preferred way to auto update a datetime field in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with 3 datetime fields:
1.`created_at` (generated and handled by Laravel),
2.`updated_at` (generated and handled by Laravel),
3.`custom_date` (created by mine, it will be changed every time `created_at` or `updated_at` is changed).

I would that every time that a new record is created or the first two fields are changed, the `custom_date` is updated using a callback.
How can achieve this using Eloquent in Laravel 5.7?

I have already tried using a mutator but I would avoid it because I would update the field every time `created_at` or `updated_at` are changed.

Comment: Why should `created_at` ever change? And why name that field `removed_at`?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do.. some code would be nice

Comment: I've changed the name of the custom field to avoid misconception. My goal is have an additional datetime field which it can be updated automatically if the `created_at` or `updated_at` are added/ changed.

Comment: For what purpose, and with what rules? You could use Eloquent events for this, but you may not need a database column at all if it's always the same rules off the value of `updated_at` - an accessor would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should have made the configuration on your migration file like so:

```
$table->timestamp('custom_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

This way, the `custom_date` field will update:

1.) When the row was created together with `created_at` field (on you laravel app).

2.) When the row was updated together with `updated_at` field (on you laravel app).

3.) When you made any modification directly to the database.

Comment: I strongly suspect OP wants the custom date field to have a non-`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value, like a "subscription expires at" sort of thing that's X weeks/days/etc. in the future.

Comment: my answer was based on what he said: **"I would that every time that a new record is created or the first two fields are changed, the custom_date is updated"** Based on my understanding, he wants the `custom_date` field be updated if the `created_at` and the `updated_at` change their values. And I believe that he could have achieved it on the migration. With this, it would be like a set-it and forget-it kind of thing.

Comment: Again, just because OP wants the date to change doesn't necessarily mean they want it changed to the *current* timestamp. Hence my asking for the rules involved.

Comment: I got your point, but I'm still confused with the question. I hope that the OP would get back and give more details. thank you @ceejayoz